# select unique items and mark them js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, class

I have multiple images and number that match eachother by class name, each number has its corresponding image so I have multiple pairs, when I select an image or number both need to have the same css class

```
   $('p[class^="pieza"], div[class^="pieza"]').on('click', function(e) {
    // remove class to all elements
    $('p[class^="pieza"], div[class^="pieza"]').removeClass('shadow');
    
    // add class to all elements having current class....
     $('.' + e.target.classList.toString().addClass('shadow');
```

the code works fine if I click on the number, number and image are selected and have the same css class

[image]

but when i click on any image, all of them got the class and its number match doesn't
[image]

Comment: Is this: $(unique).addClas('selected') supposed to be: $(unique).addClass('selected') ?

Comment: Please add code that has no syntax errors, no one can help you like this. addClas should be addClass, also your code will throw errror near  items.filter() as filter expects a function as first param

Comment: yes it is Class, sorry for the filter I'm learning

Comment: @LuzBritez I'm sorry. You added images. From images I cannot understand. I need the relevant HTML fragment and js...... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not worth too much finding unique elements.

You can directly use current clicked element class:

```js
$('p[class^="pieza"], div[class^="pieza"]').not(':has(img)').on('click', function(e) {
    // remove class to all elements
    $('p[class^="pieza"], div[class^="pieza"]').not(':has(img)').removeClass('redColor');

    // add class to all elements having current class....
    $('.' + e.target.classList.toString()).not(':has(img)').addClass('redColor');
})
```

```css
.redColor {
    background-color: red;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="pieceRow1">
    <p class="pieza18" id="pieza18">18</p>
    <p class="pieza17" id="pieza17">17</p>
    <p class="pieza16" id="pieza16">16</p>
    <p class="pieza15" id="pieza15">15</p>
</div>

<div class="fila1 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="pieza18 "><img class="img-responsive" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="pieza17"><img class="img-responsive" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="pieza16"><img class="img-responsive" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="pieza17"><img class="img-responsive" src="../../imagenes/caraDentalVacia.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i work but only when i select the number, when i click on the image all the images get the class

Comment: @LuzBritez Now no image get the class

Comment: Each image has its corresponding number, related by the class so when I click on one of the two, both must have a shadow, when I click on another image or number the previous combo must stop having the css class and repeat what I explained first, nothing else

Comment: @LuzBritez This was how snippet worked. Now I changed, but..... I don't understand. Please, create a snippet/fiddle......